# Regex Conditional Matching in One Capture Group

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string that may come in the form:

```
"filename.first_order.png"
"filename.second_order.png"
"filename.png"
"filename.(jpg|tif|etc)"
```

I need to match the first part of the string containing the name, and the extension - however, if the string is a first/second order type, I need to match "first_order"/"second_order" as the second group, and not "png", and I can't get those two conditions to co-exist in one capture group. Example matches:

```
imageondisk.first_order.png -> [imageondisk, first_order]
anotherfile.png             -> [anotherfile, png]
meetingminutes.jpeg         -> [meetingminutes, jpeg]
```

I feel like I've used all sorts of combinations of lookaheads, lookbehinds, ?s which must look like a desparate uneducated mess, but whatever I do, I can never get a result where they don't conflict when I join them together - which would look something like

```
(.+)\.(tif|jpg|<png when not preceded by first/second_order>|<first/second_order, ignoring the .png on the end>)
```

Except I just went down a frustrating rabbit hole of non-capture groups and lookarounds that seemed to end in the same place, and I feel like I knew less regex than before.

Help would hugely appreciated.

Comment: Hi It would be good if you edit your question adding a little bit more details as in: some sample data with examples of what should match and what shouldn't and why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex, which captures the filename in group 1, any first/second order string in group 2 and the extension in group 3:

```
^([^.]+)(?:\.(.+))?\.(png|jpg|tif)$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/V1naUn/2)